# Weller WES51 issue

Tags: repair, soldering-iron-station

My soldering station is a Weller WES51

Today the station died, the LED didn't turn on and the tip doesn't heat.

I opened the station and checked the transformer power switch and voltages in the controller board. Everything appears to be ok.

When I tried to verify the clock in the microcontroller (PIC) and touched the oscilloscope ground probe to the common of the controller,  the station works.

I tested the continuity with success in every common point that   I've found. The station starts to work as soon as I connect ANY of the common points to ground (which is weird.)

If I connect the transformer core (that is grounded) to one of the secondary outputs the station works.

There is continuity between the tip of the  station and the ground terminal.

Any ideas why this is happening?

I couldn't find the Weller WES51 schematic. Does anybody know where I can find it?

[image]

Comment: Sorry your station died.  Cool problem though!

Comment: Someone else found it: [music-electronics-forum.com/forum/instrumentation/pickup-makers/tools-and-coil-winding-gear/909446-weller-wes51-died](https://music-electronics-forum.com/forum/instrumentation/pickup-makers/tools-and-coil-winding-gear/909446-weller-wes51-died)

Answer (score 3):

I think what's happening here is that your oscilloscope ground and your soldering iron common are connected to the same node, however the soldering iron common connection is broken somewhere.

By connecting the iron's common to the oscilliscope ground, you are effectively completing the circuit so that the current can flow again.

I recommend checking for any broken ground connections. To do this, I would probe all the ground connections along the soldering iron electronics while it is off, checking to see that all the nodes are in fact connected to each other. If there's a broken connection somewhere, that's probably your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check fuse, is a green one on the other side of the board 4AIE 4 amp 125V, check zener diode 1N4148, the crystal diode with a red band